# How to create a boolean state array (for which only one element is True) from multiple boolean sub-state arrays?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, indexing, boolean, python-itertools

**The Set-Up:**

I am trying to build a learning agent for a simple game built in pygame. In this game, the agent must keep track of the `sub_state` of various objects; each `sub_state` is a 1-dimensional boolean array, in which it is possible to have any/all/zero `True` values. As a minimal working example, consider the following:

```
import numpy as np

sub_state_a = np.array([
    False,
    ])
    # False,
    # True])

sub_state_b = np.array([
    True,
    ])
    # False,
    # True,
    # False,
    # False])

sub_state_c = np.array([
    True])

sub_states = [
    sub_state_a,
    sub_state_b,
    sub_state_c]

# for sub_state_index, sub_state in enumerate(sub_states):
#     print("\n .. SUB-STATE (index={}; shape={}):\n{}\n".format(
#         sub_state_index,
#         sub_state.shape,
#         sub_state))
```

In the example above, there is a total of `1 + 1 + 1 = 3 # (3 + 5 + 1 = 9)` sub-states total. Because each of these `3` sub-states can take on only one of `2` possible values (`True` or `False`), the total number of unique possible states is `2 ** 3 = 8`. In other words, there are `8` unique combinations of sub-states, such that only one state is `True` at any given time/frame.

By this logic, there would be `2 ** 1 = 2` possible unique states (T or F) had there been `1` sub-state instead of `8`; there would be `2 ** 2 = 4` possible unique states (TT, TF, FT, FF) had there been `2` sub-states instead of `8`; and so on.

The code snippet below uses `concatenated_sub_states` to initialize the `state` array.

```
concatenated_sub_states = np.concatenate((sub_states))
number_sub_states = concatenated_sub_states.size

# print("\n .. CONCATENATED SUB-STATES (shape={}; number_sub_states={}):\n{}\n".format(
#     concatenated_sub_states.shape,
#     number_sub_states,
#     concatenated_sub_states))
```

```
number_states = int(2 ** number_sub_states)
states = np.full(
    number_states,
    False,
    dtype=bool)

print("\n .. STATES (shape={}; number_states={}):\n{}\n".format(
    states.shape,
    number_states,
    states))

## .. STATES (shape=(8,); number_states=8):
## [False False False False False False False False]
```

**The Question:**

I would like to use the boolean arrays in `sub_states` to select the index of the array `states` that should be set to `True`. For example, `states[0]=True` when `np.all(np.invert(concatenated_sub_states))`; `states[1]=True` when `concatenated_sub_states[0]=True` but is `False` for all other indices; and so on.

I imagine there is a way to do this with `itertools.groupby` or `numpy` magic, but I am stuck wondering how. In case the question is not clear, what function can be written that takes `sub_states` as input and outputs the index of `states` that should be set to True?

One approach I have been mulling over is the following:

```
running_product = 1
for each sub_state in sub_states:
    index_loc = np.where(sub_state)\[0]
    running_product *= np.prod(index_loc)
offset = ... # ????
state_index = int(2 ** running_product - offset)
```

Answer (score 0):

If instead of `booleans` we write them as `1` or `0`, we basically get a binary number (for your example it would be `011`). Once we have a binary string (call it `binary_num`), we can turn it into a base-10 number by just doing `int(binary_num, 2)`. So now we are missing the middle part, how to go from an array of bools to a string that just concatenates the bools. For this we use the function [`np.array2string`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html) with the keyword argument `separator=""` so that we have no spaces between the numbers. Put it all together:

```
# one array with the values of the different lists stacked
# your example: np.array([False, True, True])
sub_states = np.hstack([sub_state_a, sub_state_b, sub_state_c]) 

# your example: '[011]'
sub_states = np.array2string(sub_states.astype(int), separator = "")

# your example: print(int("011",2)), which is just print(3)
print(int(sub_states.strip("[").strip("]"),2))
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: I think there is typo in your answer: `sub_states` should be `my_array` in the line where you call `np.array2string(...)`. If this is the case, then should the returned/printed index `3` be `2` instead? I ask because there are 3 `concatenated_sub_states`, so the largest index allowed should be `2`). Maybe the last line should read `int(...) - 1`?

I find your idea of using a binary representation for the purpose of indexing is rather clever. Even if the edits mentioned above are accounted for, the code will not work for sub_states consisting of more than one element (ie, `sub_state_a`, etc)

Comment: You're right about the my_array thing, I was using a different name in testing. But I think you're mixing something up. Your `states` array will have 8 entries, not 3. What my code gives you is a 1-to-1 correspondence between your `n` different `bools` and your `2**n` different states.